# How to parse thorugh a list of links using a loop using beautiful soup?

Tags: list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am newbie in coding so please go easy. I have this work thing that I want to automate a bit.
I have to collect data from this government [website](https://nclt.gov.in/order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ%3D%3D&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ%3D%3D&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg%3D%3D).
But I think it is designed this way to prevent it from bots and DDOS attacks. What I have to do as part of my work is to click individually on these links, record the case

1. Filling date
2. Last listed date
3. Party name
4. Case status
5. If case status ='disposed' then I read and check the pdfs for reason of disposal. (which can't automated).

Now, I have to go through many pages of this and its hard to even copy paste this much info. So for the first 4 details, I tried to create a script. One of them retrieves the hyperlinks from table page, and the second script to go through the list of links and get the listed above details.  Its the second script where I am facing the problems.

**List of changes in the URL:**

```
    case_list = [
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjA4MjAyMA==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjA5MjAyMA==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjEwMjAyMA==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjExMjAyMQ==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjEyMjAyMQ==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjEzMjAyMA==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjE0MjAyMA==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjE2MjAyMQ==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjE3MjAyMA==",
    "case-details?bench=YW1yYXZhdGk=&filing_no=MjgxMjEyOTAwMjIwMjAyMA=="]
```

**URL:**

```
            response= requests.get(url)
            soup= BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser').text
             tr= soup.find_all('td')
status = tr[19].text
#gets Filing date
filing_date = tr[3].text
#gets title
case_title = tr[5].text
#gets case disposed date
disposal_date = tr[15].text
```

*Function for grabbing details from the URL:*

```
def get_case_components(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    tr = soup.find_all('td')
    
    status = tr[19].text
    
    #gets Filing date
    filing_date = tr[3].text
    #gets title
    case_title = tr[5].text
    #gets disposed date
    disposal_date = tr[15].text
    
    
    
    return filing_date, case_title, status, disposal_date
```

*Function for appending the DataFrame:*

```
def get_case(df):

    # loop for going through the case_list

    for links in url_list :
    url = links


       #putting the URL in the function

        get_case_components(url)
        df = df.append( {"filing_date": filing_date,
        "case_title" : case_title, "status": status, 
        "disposal_date": disposal_date}, ignore_index=True)
        time.sleep(1)
       

        return df
```

*Calling the `get_info()` function using Dataframe.*

```
df= pd.DataFrame(columns = ["filing_date", "case_title", "status", "disposal_date"])
df = get_case(df)
df.head()
```

For some reason I just keep getting the same thing over and over again as output, like only one case fills the entire Dataframe.

```
0   14-12-2020  Rajani Jagarlamudi VS Sharadakrupa Cold Storag...   Pending 16-03-2022 \t 
1   14-12-2020  Rajani Jagarlamudi VS Sharadakrupa Cold Storag...   Pending 16-03-2022 \t 
2   14-12-2020  Rajani Jagarlamudi VS Sharadakrupa Cold Storag...   Pending 16-03-2022 \t 
3   14-12-2020  Rajani Jagarlamudi VS Sharadakrupa Cold Storag...   Pending 16-03-2022 \t 
4   14-12-2020  Rajani Jagarlamudi VS Sharadakrupa Cold Storag...   Pending 16-03-2022 \t
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a script that gets the cases and stores them in an array.

The problem in your script was that you were manually selecting the cases when you were doing:

```py
tr = soup.find_all('td')

status = tr[19].text

#gets Filing date
filing_date = tr[3].text

#gets title
case_title = tr[5].text

#gets disposed date
disposal_date = tr[15].text
```

My code dynamically scrapes them, so you don't have to worry about it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from dataclasses import dataclass

HOST = "https://nclt.gov.in/"

LINK = "https://nclt.gov.in/order-judgement-date-wise-search?bench=Y2hlbm5haQ%3D%3D&start_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMQ%3D%3D&end_date=MDEvMDEvMjAyMg%3D%3D"

@dataclass
class Case:
    number: str
    filing_num: str
    case_no: str
    pvr: str
    listing_date: str
    status: str

def get_cases(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        print("getting cases")
        return res.text

def extract_case(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    cases = [Case(*[td.text for td in tr.select("td")]) for tr in soup.select("table tbody tr")]
    next, *rest = [link["href"] for link in soup.select(".page-link") if link.text.strip() == "Next"]
    if len(next):
        next = HOST + next
    return cases, next
    
def main():
    total_cases = []
    next = ""
    amount = int(input("How many pages do you want to scrape?"))
    oamount = amount
    while amount:
        if len(next) and oamount != amount:
            html = get_cases(next)
        else:
            html = get_cases(LINK)
        cases, next = extract_case(html)
        total_cases.extend(cases)
        amount -= 1
        print(cases, next)

    print("Scraped", len(total_cases), "cases")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Woah, that helped a lot!, Is there any way I can convert this into a dataframe?

Comment: @simrpal from a quick search, I think you can do it easily by doing `df = pd.DataFrame(total_cases, columns = ['Number', 'Filing No', 'Case No', 'P vs R', 'Listing Date', 'Status'])`.